# Create column by contains in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill up a new column `df1.new_col` with the corresponding `df2.C` value if the string in `df1.A` is included in `df2.B` of the same row:

`df1`

```
    A           X     Y     Z
0   code        ...   ...   ...
1   other       ...   ...   ...
2   medium      ...   ...   ...
    ...
```

`df2`:

```
    B               C         P      Q
0   small/medium    ID 20     ...    ...
1   large           ID 2      ...    ...
2   other part      ID 8      ...    ...
3   code 01         ID 9      ...    ...
    ...
```

Expected output:

```
    A        new_col       X     Y     Z
0   code     ID 9          ...   ...   ...
1   other    ID 8          ...   ...   ...
2   medium   ID 20         ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: Does the `df1.A` column contains only unique values?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo yes

Comment: Should the values of new_col be the sum of the occurances of C (if more than one)?

Comment: @Ricardo It's very unlikely, but just in case, can we join the strings please? I've updated C values

Comment: Can you add some code, what you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get all words to lists by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), then [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with aggregate `join` if possible duplciates and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['B'] = df2['B'].str.findall('(\w+)')

s = df2.explode('B').groupby('B')['C'].agg(','.join)

#inserted second column
df1.insert(1, 'new_col',  df1['A'].map(s))
#added last column
#df1['new_col'] = df1['A'].map(s)
print (df1)
        A new_col   X   Y   Z
0    code    ID 9 NaN NaN NaN
1   other    ID 8 NaN NaN NaN
2  medium   ID 20 NaN NaN NaN
```